# Get data from array with object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, vue.js

I´m trying to access to array and get value `"estado"`. I´m working with `vuejs` and `laravel`. I´m trying with any way, but i can´t... I know that my question maybe it´s very easy or simple...

My array it´s:

```
[{"tarea_id":"15359","estado":2,"fechaHora":"2023-06-20 13:16:30.787","name":null},{"tarea_id":"15359","estado":0,"fechaHora":"2023-06-20 13:16:29.787","name":null}]
```

My code to show data en webrowser it´s:

```
{{ scope.row.estadosFicheros }}
```

If i try with: `scope.row.estadosFicheros[0]` show `[` if i try to ge info in `scope.row.estadosFicheros.estado` return `undefined` if i do `JSON.parse(scope.row.estadosFicheros)` return  what i wrote at the beginning
if i do after parse `.estado` return `undefined` if i do ["estado"] same problem

I tryed with `strigify` i can show this: `[{\"tarea_id\":\"15365\",\"estado\":1,\"fechaHora\":\"2023-06-20 13:35:55.227\",\"name\":null},{\"tarea_id\":\"15365\",\"estado\":0,\"fechaHora\":\"2023-06-20 13:35:35.117\",\"name\":null}]"`

if i try to get `estado` with `.estado` not show anything.

What i´m doing wrong? how i can to access this array with object?

Thanks for readme and sorry for my bad english

Comment: Assuming `scope.row.estadosFicheros` is the reference to the array, then `scope.row.estadosFicheros[0].estado` will get you the value from the first object in the array. If you need all values, then you can use a loop incrementing the `[0]` index as you go.

Comment: Make and example of what you have on https://play.vuejs.org/ (and link it), then your question will become easy and understandable

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan this it´s my problem that if i do ```scope.row.estadosFicheros[0].estado``` not show anyting

Comment: @Dimava i cant to do reproduce example, because, if i create my array and try access to ```data[0].estado``` i can access ok. (```DATA``` its my example array)

Comment: Try `JSON.parse(scope.row.estadosFicheros)[0].estado`. that will parse your content, and then get the first element, and grab `estado` from the object.

Comment: @NilsKähler thanks for your response. You resolve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you need to parse your data before you access it.

You need to parse your data first. `JSON.parse(scope.row.estadosFicheros)` this will give you an object. After that you can access your object eg. `JSON.parse(scope.row.estadosFicheros)[0].estado`

I have created an example of how your data probably looks to better understand the problem you are encountering.

```js
const scope = {row: { estadosFicheros: '[{"tarea_id":"15359","estado":2,"fechaHora":"2023-06-20 13:16:30.787","name":null},{"tarea_id":"15359","estado":0,"fechaHora":"2023-06-20 13:16:29.787","name":null}]'}}; // Mocking your data
const data = JSON.parse(scope.row.estadosFicheros)
console.log(data[0].estado);
```